# Disappearing elements while using SHAKE effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to figure out this framework, but I am having problems with implementing shaking effect. Everytime I hover over element other divs just dissappear. In fiddle i tried different JQuery and JQuery ui and it was working but selecting newest one just breaks the whole thing. ANy tips? Thank you!

https://jsfiddle.net/w11qknc4/

```
$( ".box" ).mouseenter(function() {
$( this ).effect( "shake", { direction: "up", times: 4, distance: 10}, 1000 );
$( this ).finish().effect( "shake", { direction: "up", times: 4, distance: 2}, 1000 );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is not necessary and causes your issue :

> $( this ).finish().effect( "shake", { direction: "up", times: 4, distance: 2}, 1000 );

Just use :

```
$( ".box" ).mouseover(function() {
  $(this).effect( "shake", { direction: "up", times: 4, distance: 2}, 1000 );
});
```

---

If you wish to wait the end of an effect before another, see use :

```
var start = true,
    delay = 1000;

$(".box").mouseover(function() {
  if (start) {
    start = false;
    $(this).effect("shake", { direction: "up", times: 4, distance: 2}, delay);

    setTimeout(function () {
      start = true;
    }, delay)
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time! I tried that, but when I remove finish() my animation is just queueing up. I have tried to use stop or clearQueue, but that just causes my elements to move up. Thank you!